# "Then our enemies are fortunate" as a response to "today is a good day to die"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, episode-identification, klingon

A friend of mine remembers a scene in DS9, which she believes was an exchange between Worf and Ezri Dax, where Worf says the immortal Klingon line:

> Today is a good day to die.

To which Ezri replies with:

> Then our enemies are fortunate.

Unfortunately, my friend can not remember the exact wording or the episode. I have hunted for references to this, but I can't find this (or similar exchange) occurring in any episode.

Does my friend misremember? Or did these lines appear in DS9, possibly in a cut scene?

Comment: Fictional quote in Patton: "I want you to remember that no bastard ever won a war by dying for his country. He won it by making the other poor, dumb bastard die for his country.".

Comment: Not fictional - see http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/04/24/war/ - and though Patton said it, it wasn't entirely original.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Searching [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/) (the go-to site for all Star Trek and Doctor Who transcripts) gave [only six results](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?si=98804524&pid=r&n=0&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%EF%BF%BD&query=%22good+day+to+die%22) in the whole of Star Trek for the phrase "good day to die" (in quotes). In none of its occurrences is this phrase followed by anything close to "Then our enemies are fortunate".

Searching for ["enemies are fortunate"](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?oq=%22good+day+to+die%22&id=98804524&pageid=r&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&scs=1&query=%22enemies+are+fortunate%22&Find=Search&mode=ALL&search=all) or ["enemies are lucky"](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?oq=%22enemies+are+fortunate%22&id=98804524&pageid=r&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&scs=1&query=%22enemies+are+lucky%22&Find=Search&mode=ALL) (both in quotes) gave no results whatsoever.Nor did searching for ["enemies' fortune"](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?oq=%22enemies+are+lucky%22&id=98804524&pageid=r&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&scs=1&query=%22enemies%27+fortune%22&Find=Search&mode=ALL) or ["enemies' good fortune"](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?oq=%22enemies%27+fortune%22&id=98804524&pageid=r&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&scs=1&query=%22enemies%27+good+fortune%22&Find=Search&mode=ALL), or other variants I tried.

I also tried some Google searches, including Deep Space Nine, Worf, and Ezri in the search terms so as to narrow down the possibilities, but still no joy.

**It looks as though this exchange doesn't occur anywhere in Star Trek.** Sorry.

Comment: I've also looked and I can't find anything. Which is weird, because I very vaguely remember something similar. But yeah, I've looked over every single Ezri line and no dice. Maybe it was in a game, or an image, or maybe someone else said something similar, maybe even in a different franchise. Jesus... that narrows it down.

Comment: Huh, weird. I feel like I remember something like this too. Unhelpfully, I can’ remember what.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite agreed. Maybe we all are having a collective hallucination. It does sound familiar but I can't place it though.

Comment: "Every day is a good day to die if you're fighting your enemies"? https://www.google.nl/search?q=good+day+to+die+enemies+fortunate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=O5AOV-SdH4f7PqTCo-gC

Comment: In the first episode found by that search, "Blood Oath", right at the end, *Kang* says "It is a good day to die", and *Jadzia* Dax responds "It's never a good day to lose a friend".  Different Klingon, different incarnation of Dax, but similar in spirit.  Maybe that's what people are thinking of?

Comment: It could possibly be from a novel. I haven't read any DS9 novels, so it's just a guess.

Comment: @MatthewGreen: Look around you. Do you see Earth's moon anywhere?

Comment: That was a lot of hard searching to be so concise in proving a negative. I have to grant you an accepted answer after that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Further information; it may have been in a scene that was cut from the episode and seen in an unofficial setting. *shrug * dating a true Trekker - that's why I shaved my head. - Your answer is comprehensive and will remain accepted, unless anyone can pull some amazing feat of nerdness out of thin air.

Comment: @Petersaber For all we know it could have been characters of "Big Bang Theory" quoting Star Trek and making up their own come-back line...

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I searched on the internet for any deleted scenes featuring Worf and Ezri, but still no luck.

Comment: Fun to note that this question is now the top search result for the phrase, "Then our enemies are fortunate." Following results a clearly pages where this one showed up in the Hot Network questions. ([Math.SE] pages and the like.)

Answer (score 21):

A variation of the OP's line is actually found twice in the trilogy *Star Trek: Destiny*. The first time comes in Book 1, *Gods of Night* (Chapter 15). The Klingon High Council is debating whether or not to join Starfleet in their war against the Borg. (emphasis mine)

> With a clenched jaw and bitter grimace, Kopek extended his open right hand to Martok, who took it. “*Qapla’*, Chancellor.” A feral gleam shone in his eyes as he released Martok’s hand, turned, and declared with a raised fist, “To war!”
>
> The councillors roared their approval, and Martok flashed a broad, jagged grin. **"It is a good day to die … for the Borg."**

Later on in Book 2, *Mere Mortals* (Chapter 4), Captain Krogan of the *I.K.S. veScharg'a* thinks to himself: *It is a good day to die...for my enemies*, as he is defending his Klingon homeworld from the Borg. (emphasis mine)

> More blasts shook the *veScharg’a*. Krogan reveled as he watched the viewer and saw the aft-angle view of the torpedoes hitting home and blasting one Borg cube to pieces in a sapphire flash. As the blue fire cloud dissipated into the vacuum of space, another cerulean blast filled the starscape behind it, as the second Borg cube was annihilated.
>
> The bridge officers cheered and roared at their victory. Krogan permitted himself a satisfied growl and a nod of his head. ***It is a good day to die … for my enemies.***